# Swift - Starting a game with out pressing the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am making a game that, when the game loads in, doesn't require the user to tap the screen to start, but starts straight away.

**My code with the "tap to start":**

```
import Foundation
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

    var isStarted = false

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        //backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()

        addTapToStartLabel()

    func addTapToStartLabel() {
        let tapToStartLabel = SKLabelNode(text: "Tap to start!")
        tapToStartLabel.name = "tapToStartLabel"
        tapToStartLabel.position.x = view!.center.x
        tapToStartLabel.position.y = view!.center.y + 40
        tapToStartLabel.fontColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        tapToStartLabel.fontName = "Helvetica"
        tapToStartLabel.fontSize = 22.0
        addChild(tapToStartLabel)
    }

    func start() {
        isStarted = true

        let tapToStartLabel = childNodeWithName("tapToStartLabel")
        tapToStartLabel?.removeFromParent()

        square1.stop()
        movingGround.start()
        wallGen.startGenWallsEvery(1)
        diamondGen.startGenDiamondsEvery(1)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        if isGameOver {
            restart()
        } else if !isStarted {
            start()
        } else {
            square1.flip()
        }
    }
```

I have tried a couple of things and I can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your didMoveToView is missing }
Your game have started, but you should override update() function that is called at the beginning of every frame and do some actions there.

Comment: I know because you do not need that, I have just typed the code that I need to start the game.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, I know my game starts but I want it to start with out anyone tapping the screen

Comment: When you run game does label comes up on screen or is screen empty? Right now (based on code you provided) it looks to me, that when game starts you display label on screen that user can tap and then square will flip or stop? Why don't you just call start()  in didMoveToView (and remove code for label since it is not needed any more)? No need to call addTapToStartLabel() at all.

Comment: Ahh now I got it! Thanks a lot man, kinda new to swift and programming overall so I am starting to get the hang of things

Comment: No problem my friend :). We help each other all the time. Happy coding :)